# CSS Navbar not in the correct order?

Tags: html

I'm messing with my navbar for my CSS-Framework. The Code I got so far, will be linked in a hastebin. The Problem is, that the "li"s will not be displayed in the correct order. Hope someone can help!

CSS: http://hastebin.com/yucatebero.css

HTML: http://hastebin.com/wikitaxeli.xml

The Probleme: https://gyazo.com/c61e26cad3048a85eb40cd9dfa6b83d0

```
 nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    background: #f96e5b;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {}

.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tkL4f920/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its the floating that is causing you pain. Change the order in the html to apply the simple fix.

Comment: The  "you" comes first in the html so it gets the styles applied first. It floats to the right then "today" floats to the right - is how i think about it.

Comment: It is because of the float:right property contained in navbar-right class in your li tags. The elements will stack from the left to right.

Comment: @Radmation and noone of you guys know how to make it possible to enter the correct order in the html so it get's correctly displayed on the website? Because this is for a Framework and for that it would be better to work correctly...

Comment: @ManuelAzar same question to you ;)

Comment: Instead of using hastebin you should make a working example on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) or on [plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/) :)

Comment: the fiddle shows syntax errors, please fix them first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the "you" "today" with a div with navbar-right if you wish to keep the order.

```
<div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">How</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">are</a></li>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">you</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">today</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/tkL4f920/1/

Comment: that's pretty nice, but is there a workaround way in CSS? So that you can easly list them up in html and it auto styls it in css whithout any problems

Comment: @BennetG. I would look into flexbox - it will change your css classes most likely but not your html structure. You can reorder elements with flexbox.